# Add a UINavigationController nested inside a container view controller to a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, containment

I have a `UIViewController` (red) set as the first tab of a `UITabBarController` as shown in the storyboard below. This view controller is a container view controller and loads a `UINavigationController` inside its `contentView` (the white rectangle inside the red view controller).

[image: Storyboard]

This is my code for loading the navigation controller inside the red view controller's `contentView`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // instantiate navigation controller
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"N"];

    // place navigation controller inside content view
    [self addChildViewController:navigationVC];
    navigationVC.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;
    [self.containerView addSubview:navigationVC.view];
    [navigationVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

From what I know about view controller containment this *should* work as I am explicitly setting the frame for the navigation controller. However, when there are enough cells in the `tableView` to exceed the container's height there is always a bar at the end of the `tableView` when I scroll down. I have set the `tableView`'s `backgroundColor` to *orange* and the cell's `backgroundColor` to *white* in order to see the difference.

[image: Gap at the end of the tableView]

How do I get rid of that orange gap at the end of the `tableView`?

(Note: I am *not* using autolayout and I need a solution that works for both - iOS7 *and* iOS6.)

Comment: set the tableView's background colour as nil, then wt's the problem with that .

Comment: The color of the `tableView` doesn't matter. It's the gap or the "extra row" that shouldn't be there.

Comment: I think that child VC (navigation controller) is respecting the parent tab bar.

Comment: I agree. The question is: How do I make the table view controller understand that it should *not* respect the parent tab bar itself? Because obviously the navigation view controller adjusts its height with respect to the tab bar correctly and it's not the table view's job to do that...

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: Did you figure that out? Maybe `containerVC.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;` can work?

Answer (score 4):

I know you are also looking for an answer which works on iOS 6, but on iOS 7 and above you can use

```
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
```

Comment: It also can be defined on InterfaceBuilder on Attributes Inspector -> View Controller -> Extend Edges: Under Opaque bars

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;` in `-(void)viewDidLoad` of `Table View Controller - Root`?

**Note**: iOS 7 only

Comment: I need a solution that works for iOS 6 as well (updated my question). But I have also tried your suggestion and it did not work in iOS 7.