# Why does UINavigationController have an unexpected size inside a container view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am working on a iOS (Swift) project. I am trying to embed a UINavigationController inside a container view. As seen:

[image: Hierarchy]

It goes: UITabBarController -> UIViewController: container view -> UINavigationController -> UIViewController

I have hidden the Navigation Bar and Toolbar for the UINavigationController

Everytime I run it, I am getting this result (the red is the container views background)

[image: Result]

Why is this happening? and how can I get rid of the red bar and make the tableview fill the whole container view?

BTW: If I embed the table view to the container view directly, I don't have this problem. It only seems to happen when using a navigation controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks similar to an issue I've had before concerning the `setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` property on  `UIViewController`. Try playing with that on your `FilterViewController`.

Another thing you could try is setting constraints around your table view inside your `FilterViewController` to make sure it is attached to the edges of the view. (This can be ignored if `FilterViewController` is a subclass of `UITableViewController`).

Comment: Hi Mark thanks for your response, I have constrained the TableView in FilterViewController and tried adjusting setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets on FilterViewController and the navigation controller. It is unfortunately still producing the same output.

Comment: Hmm, is it possible to give me access to a simple reproducer project? Would be easier to debug that way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27149012/1570786
The above method works fine in iOS8, in iOS7 it doesn't work as expected.